# repeat.tex and \date: Not working with ngerman option

Tags: date

How to get the right date in a German document using the `repeat.tex` file? This can be found on ctan.org under [repeat.tex](https://ctan.org/pkg/repeat). I always get the english version.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\KOMAoptions{%  
    ,fontsize   = 12pt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%%
\include{repeat}
\title{Title}
\date{\today}
%%
\begin{document}
%%
\maketitle
%%
I am using \verb!repeat.tex!, Version 0.93a, September 2006. 
\verb!fontsize=12pt! is working but not the \verb!\date! macro. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: never use \include before begin document

Comment: and as already told to you, don't use repeat.tex. It breaks various loops.

Comment: Why are you keen to employ a particular (plain-TeX) implementation of a macro named `\repeat`, which you fully well know breaks `babel` -- and probably quite a few other standard LaTeX packages too?

Comment: @Mico not only packages, many core commands, such as `\mulicolumn` or `filecontents` use `\loop` or `\repeat` so it breaks latex itself, not only packages....

Comment: @Davit Ups, right, but will not chance the game

Comment: @Mico Do you ask me? I am not the owner of this tex-file.  It is part of the igo-package (https://ctan.org/pkg/igo) and necessary for using this package. And I just learned that it has implications e.g. the babel package (e.g. the date). But more I don't know.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer already informed you yesterday that the definition of `\repeat` in the file `repeat.tex` is guaranteed to break all kinds of things (including `babel`) in a LaTeX document. She, in essence, also suggested that if you simply must use the `ugo` package, you should change the name of the macro (say, from `\repeat` to `\Repeat`) in a suitably modified and renamed version of `repeat.tex` and that you change the instances of `\repeat` in `ugo.sty` from  `\repeat` to `\Repeat`.

Comment: @Mico then I will try your suggestions.